# Boundedness of a function with singular integrand

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I’m studying the following function
$$f(t)=\int_0^t (t-s)^{-\frac{3}{4}}s^{-\frac{1}{4}}ds.$$
It is clear that $f(t) >0$ for $t\in (0,1],$ since $-\frac{3}{4}>-1$ and $-\frac{1}{4}>-1$.

I want to know if there exists $C>0$ such that for all $t \in (0,1],$ $$f(t) \le C.$$

Also, I’d like to know if $\lim_{t\to 0^+} f(t)$ exists.

I would be appreciate it if you give any comments for my questions.

Comment: Just make the substitution $s=tx; ds=t\,dx$, and you will see what happens ...

Comment: @Svyatoslav Wow. What a surprise! It’s just a constant. Thanks a lot.